# How can I create below design using negative border radius?

Tags: css

[image]

I have done something like this,

Code:

```css
body {
  background: #3c3c3c;
}

.favorites-container {
  color: #4a4a4a;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -26px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "ProximaNova-Regular", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 8px 10px 0px 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 14px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 14px;
  border-top-left-radius: 14px;
}

.favorites-container:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 8px;
  width: 29px;
  bottom: 11px;
  left: -28px;
  border-radius: 0 0 20px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 20px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 20px 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 0 0 0 #fff;
  box-shadow: 10px 0 0 0 #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<br><br>
<div class="favorites-container">
  3.5k
  <span class="fa fa-heart-o"></span>
</div>
```

but it was not pixel perfect. Is there any way to use negative border radius for this?

Comment: The is no negative radius, use an SVG

Comment: You can try something along theese examples, but else, go with an image overlay, svg or png. https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/